ASG and Cluster Service with redudant Network Settings like VPC and Subnet. Why?
Why we have Separate Network Settings for Services in the ECS cluster when I already defined them in the ASG. Shouldn't it naturally take the same? It even shows a VPC selection.
for Eg:
I chose a VPC and 2 public subnets for ASG,
While creating service it shows option of all VPCs, and in the same VPCs shows the other subnets which are not part of ASG.
If I select a different VPC, how does that work? If I select a private subnet that is not part of ASG how does it work?
This is in part related to a cluster Service SG question here
